# Reading a table in a text file using a C program

Tags: arrays, c

Below I have a sample table stored in a text file - random.dat.

```
0.00    0.01     2.30    300
2.00    0.015    1.45    102
4.00    0.03     6.08    174
6.00    5.95     0.05    225
```

Now I want to read the contents of the table and store into an array. I have the following code that almost does the job.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
  int i,j;
  int M = 3, N = 3;
  FILE *fp;
  double value1[M][N];

  fp = fopen("random.dat","r");
  if (fp == NULL)
    {
      exit(1);
    }

  for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
          fscanf(fp, "%lf", &value1[i][j]);
          if (feof(fp))
            {
              break;
            }
         }
     }

\*Just to check that my code has stored the arrays properly, I put the following printf statements*/

  printf("%lf\n", value1[0][0]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[0][1]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[0][2]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[0][3]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[1][0]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[1][1]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[1][2]);
  printf("%lf\n", value1[1][3]);
              
}
```

The values that I want and thought the program would give me:

```
value1[0][0] = 0.00  value1[0][1] = 0.01   value1[0][2] = 2.30  value1[0][3] = 300
value1[1][0] = 2.00  value1[1][1] = 0.015  value1[1][2] = 1.45  value1[1][3] = 102
```

Instead, it gives me,

```
value1[0][0] = 0.00   value1[0][1] = 0.01  value1[0][2] = 2.30   value1[0][3] = 300.0
value1[1][0] = 300.0  value1[1][1] = 2.00  value1[1][2] = 0.015  value1[1][3] = 1.45
```

I couldn't figure out a solution for this. Can someone point where I have made an error?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If M and N are 3, value1 [0] [3] is out of bounds. Change N to 4.

Comment: I have one more question @c yj if you don't mind answering. 

If I have some text before my table, say


`Some random text` in the first line.
Followed by the table as shown in the question.

How can I read the table in the same way as I did but eliminating the text?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. The easiest way to do this is because you know that the text is on the first line. After ignoring the data in the first line, you can read the file to your variable.  char filter[1024]; fgets(filter,1024,fp); .These two lines of code will make you ignore the first line.